# Default model and handler directories with webapp2?

Tags: google-app-engine, webapp2

Is there a simple means to configure a model directory and a handler directory with webapp2 - where multiple model and handler files can be kept? The documentation seems to not have a single example where handlers are not in main.py or at the root dir.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a package; create a directory and put `__init__.py` in it. And put your model/handler modules into those directories, and import them when necessary.